# POST-запрос в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, post

Есть сайт, нужно дернуть из него инфу в формате JSON. Местами с него информацию уже вытаскивал - `requests.get('интересующий url')` и готово, но сейчас так не проканывает. Через Burp Suite выяснил, что браузер делает следующий запрос:

```
POST /getJSON/ViewInfo HTTP/1.1
Host: NoName.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 81

{"Language":"ru"}{"Params":[null, null, 1, null, null]}{"V":1}{"Adult": false}
```

Меня интересует как нужно изменить строчку кода

```
res = requests.get(url, headers=var.user_agent)
```

чтобы получить (желательно библиотекой requests) ответ на данный POST-запрос. Т.е. куда и как мне прописать заветные *{"Language":"ru"}{"Params":[null, null, 1, null, null]}{"V":1}{"Adult": false}*

Если написать вот так:

```
payload = ({"Language":"ru"},{"Params":["null", "null", 1, "null", "null"]},{"Vers":2})
res = requests.post(url, json=payload)
page = res.text
```

то все "работает", ошибок нет, ровно как и ответа. А нужен ответ.

Comment: Документацию `requests` читать пробовали? Попробуйте: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/

Comment: @zed спасибо конечно за ссылку, директиву 'params=' использовать пробовал. Переформулирую тогда вопрос, как корректно засунуть в нее _{"Language":"ru"}{"Params":[null, null, 1, null, null]}{"V":1}{"Adult": false}_? Все таки несколько фигурных скобок подряд, тут как-то по хитрому нужно. Возможно именно по этому у меня с params= и не получилось сразу, что отправлял неправильно

Comment: Вы в доках про POST читайте, а не про GET. Особенно, ту часть, где [про json пишут](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests).

Comment: @zed да, спасибо), я как раз на этом месте завис. Предположим нужно отправить payload = {"Params":[null, null, 1, null, null]}. Питон понятия не имеет что такое null, а если заключить их в апострофы это будет уже не null. Как мне указать что именно третий параметр "Params" должен быть равен 1? Конструкцию payload = {"Params"[3]=1} он разумеется не принимает, а как по другому ума не приложу

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нельзя заключать `null` в кавычки. Вы тем самым создаёте строковое значение. Вместо этого нужно использовать питоновский аналог `None`:

```
import requests

url = 'http://example.com/getJSON/ViewInfo'    
data = ({"Language": "ru"}, {"Params": [None, None, 1, None, None]}, {"V": 1}, {"Adult": False})    
res = requests.post(url, json=data)    
print res.text
```

На сервер отправится вот такой запрос:

```
POST /getJSON/ViewInfo HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.13.0
Content-Length: 89
Content-Type: application/json

[{"Language": "ru"}, {"Params": [null, null, 1, null, null]}, {"V": 1}, {"Adult": false}]
```

Как можно заметить, отправляется массив из объектов, в то время как в запросе браузера, отправляется несколько склеенных объектов (если вы, конечно, всё правильно отснифили). И по сути, в том запросе передаётся невалидный json (Multiple JSON root elements).

Если всё же нужно отправить запрос именно в таком виде, то можно сформировать данные в виде строки и прописать соответствующий `Content-Type` в заголовках запроса:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla'}    
data = '{"Language":"ru"}{"Params":[null, null, 1, null, null]}{"V":1}{"Adult": false}'
res = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

На сервер отправится запрос:

```
POST /getJSON/ViewInfo HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: Mozilla
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 78

{"Language":"ru"}{"Params":[null, null, 1, null, null]}{"V":1}{"Adult": false}
```