# POST запрос в PYTHON

Tags: python, post

Я не особо понимаю как отправлять Post запросы в Python (Вместе с куки).
Вот POST запрос, который мне нужно отправить на сервер:
[image]

Comment: POST-запрос в python https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690089/post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B2-python

Comment: Так я не знаю как их отправлять с куки и т.д. Можешь написать хотя бы пример?

Comment: [Здесь](http://python-requests.org) всё подробно описано с множеством примеров.

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests

headers = {'Accept': '*/*', 'Content-Type': '...'} # Здесь обычным словарём python указываете все свои заголовки
cookies = {'ips4_IPSSessionFront': '...'} # Аналогично с хедерами указываете куки

response = requests.post('http://www.lol.ru', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Объект `response` содержит ответ на Ваш запрос.
Полностью пример расписывать не стал, т.к. переписывать значения с приложенной Вами картинки не считаю целесообразным, думаю, суть и так ясна.